# make an array with 10 unique numbers in java

Tags: java, arraylist

it's my first time I ask here question.

I wanna make ArrayList with 10 unique int numbers from 0 to 9. 
I do next steps:

1. Create empty Arraylist
2. Add first random number, so I can check for repetition later
3. Next I create new random int value, check if I've already have this one in ArrayList. If I have - I try another number, if I have not - I add this number.
4. If I got 10 numbers, I stop the loop

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rd = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int q = rd.nextInt(10);
    list.add(q);

    while (true) {
        int a = rd.nextInt(10);
        for (int b=0;b<list.size();b++){
            if (a == list.get(b)) break;
            else list.add(a);
        }
        if (list.size() == 10) break;
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

But all I see in console is endless process.

The question is - is there another way to make ArrayList with 10 unique numbers (0 to 9)?

Comment: Why the [tag:android] tag? What does this question have to do with Android programming (note that I've removed the tag since I feel that it's likely irrelevant)? Also, to solve this, debug it. You can do this simply by printing out the data in your list and the value of `a` within your for loop to see why your logic isn't working.

Comment: Actually, the simplest solution is to use a simple for loop to fill the list sequentially, and then call `Collections.shuffle(list)` to randomize your list. Ta da, you're done!

Comment: Tis what i was just going to say @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) after initializing your `ArrayList` with the numbers.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    list.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

That will run in linear time because `ArrayList` is `RandomAccess`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 Streams

```
List<Integer> shuffled = 
   // give me all the numbers from 0 to N
   IntStream.range(0, N).boxed()
        // arrange then by a random key
        .groupBy(i -> Math.random(), toList())
        // turns all the values into a single list
        .values().flatMap(List::stream).collect(toList());
```